# Adjusting node_prefix variable on a pre-build binary

Tags: node.js, variables, configuration, precompiled

If I obtain a pre-built binary, is there a simple place I can go and tell this binary where it is to be stored? For example, if I obtain a binary from [here](http://www.petertribble.co.uk/Solaris/node.html), then
`process.config.variables.node_prefix == '/opt/Node'`. That is not where I will be putting it. I want to separate versions, and I want it lowercase, etc.

I know this is a very tiny wrinkle, but I would like to solve it if possible.

So is there a place I can adjust this variable, without re-building the binaries?